# Lisp Format Procedure Applied to Arrays

Tags: arrays, format, common-lisp

I need some help with the `format` function and arrays.

My objective is to print a 2 dimensional array of *N·N* integer values as *N* integers per line. For example:

```
#2A((1 2 3)
    (4 5 6)
    (7 8 9))
```

should be printed as

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how to use `format` to print arrays. Can it actually be done, or should I convert my array into a list and use something like:

```
(format t "~{~%~{~A~^ ~}~}"  list)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun show-board (board)
  (loop for i below (car (array-dimensions board)) do
        (loop for j below (cadr (array-dimensions board)) do
          (let ((cell (aref board i j)))
            (format t "~a " cell)))
        (format t "~%")))
```

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistaken, there is no direct way for `format` to go "into" an array.  You could write your own function, to be used by tilde-slash (`~/function/`, see [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm)), or you could coerce the array to a list and use either the directives you proposed, or [`~/pprint-tabular/`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ppr_fi.htm#pprint-tabular).  If you want to define your own, the CLHS has example code for `pprint-tabular` which you could modify for arrays.